# Changing bootstrap datepicker's options

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I have this script / html:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        todayBtn: true,
        todayHighlight: true,
    });
})

...

<div class="input-append date datepicker" data-date="">
    <input class="input-medium" size="16" type="text" value='' autocomplete='off' />
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>
```

The `todayBtn` and `todayHighlight` options seem not working. And I also want to set it default to today, how do I do that? (the above does set the date to today, but only in the dropdown, not in the `input`).

Also, when I remove the `data-date` attribute, the date picker is broken: dropdown becomes blank.

**UPDATE**: I am using the first Bootstrap date picker that I could find using Google: [bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) (somehow I thought that everyone uses this).

Comment: Please note you have a trailing comma. Internet Explorer doesn't like that.

Comment: As far as i am concerned bootstrap does not come with a datepicker by default so guess you are using ONE OF many bootstrap datepicker plugins. Is that correct?

Comment: I think so. Datepicker is a widget from jQuery UI

Comment: Speculating from the option names, he isn't using [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/). Voting to put on hold—this cannot be answered if we don't even know what the widget is.

Comment: Thanks for comments. Question updated.